# get different result in debug

Tags: c, pointers, struct, clion

Im having a bit of a problem while writing simple code.
when I use clion debug i get " **the  date is: 21/1/1990 and next date is -1084227472.32648**"

BUT when i put break point and follow the code in the end i get the RIGHT
answer aka "**the  date is: 21/1/1990 and next date is 22.1**"

```
typedef struct date_t* Date;
struct date_t{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    Date nextDay;

};

Date dateCreate(int day, int month, int year){
    Date newDate = malloc(sizeof(newDate));
    newDate->day = day;
    newDate->month = month;
    newDate->year = year;
    Date next = malloc(sizeof(*next));
    next->day = day+1;
    next->month = month;
    next->year = year;
    newDate->nextDay = next;

    return newDate;
}

void printDate(Date date){
    printf("the  date is: %d/%d/%d and next date is %d.%d \n", date->day,date->month,date->year, date->nextDay->day,date->nextDay->month);
}

int main() {
    Date d1 = dateCreate(21,01,1990);
    printDate(d1);}
```

Comment: `Date newDate = malloc(sizeof(newDate));` this is wrong. You allocate memory for a pointer, not enough to fit the whole struct. This is why people advise against typedefing pointers.

Comment: @DeiDei thank you, now it works. but I dont understand why. when i created a typedef dosent it means that newdate is a pointer?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the mysterious world of the infamous Undefined Behaviour.

Here

```
Date next = malloc(sizeof(*next));
```

you do it right.

Here

```
Date newDate = malloc(sizeof(newDate));
```

you don't.

The latter should be

```
Date newDate = malloc(sizeof(*newDate));
```

Comment: thank you, now it works. but I dont understand why.
when i created a typedef dosent it means that newdate is a pointer?

Comment: @tylerdurden You do not want to allocate space for a pointer, you want to allocate space for an element.